# Play framework, typesafe activator: "error loading JNotify watch service: no jnotify in java.library.path"

Tags: activator, typesafe, jnotify

I am trying to open an existing application through typesafe activator 1.3.
The error message says that JNotify is missing in java library but I've also added jnotify_64bit.dll file to the "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin" directory. But I'm still facing the error. Below is the log. It's been a while I'm stuck here and I really need some help here.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   net.contentobjects.jnotify.macosx.JNotify_macosx.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   net.contentobjects.jnotify.macosx.JNotifyAdapterMacOSX.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
>   net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify.(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$JNotifyDelegate.ensureLoaded(PlayWatchService.scala:168)
>     at
>   play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$$anonfun$5.apply(PlayWatchService.scala:223)
>     at
>   play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$$anonfun$5.apply(PlayWatchService.scala:179)
>     at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$withTry$1.apply(Exception.scala:129)
>     at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$withTry$1.apply(Exception.scala:129)
>     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:102)    at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.withTry(Exception.scala:129)   at
>   play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$.apply(PlayWatchService.scala:179)
>     at
>   play.runsupport.PlayWatchService$$anon$1.delegate$lzycompute(PlayWatchService.scala:65)
>     at
>   play.runsupport.PlayWatchService$$anon$1.delegate(PlayWatchService.scala:61)
>     at
>   play.runsupport.PlayWatchService$$anon$1.watch(PlayWatchService.scala:74)
>     at play.runsupport.Reloader.(Reloader.scala:268)  at
>   play.runsupport.Reloader$.reloader$lzycompute$1(Reloader.scala:174)
>     at
>   play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$reloader$1(Reloader.scala:174)
>     at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:197)   at
>   play.forkrun.ForkRun$.startServer(ForkRun.scala:82)   at
>   play.forkrun.ForkRun.run(ForkRun.scala:173)   at
>   play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$settingUp$1.applyOrElse(ForkRun.scala:162)
>     at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)    at
>   play.forkrun.ForkRun.aroundReceive(ForkRun.scala:148)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)  at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254)   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error of you. In my case, I've cloned a play framework(2.3.x) repository project to run the project.

I actually followed this steps:

1. `sbt clean compile`
2. `sbt evicted`
3. `set ~run`

Now, It's working well!

If this doen't work, try to change to your java and javac to 1.6 version.
Actually, until the Play 2.3 use Java 6.

Comment: Is `set` meant to be `sbt` in your last step?